# Merging meshes as well as textures in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using a model from clara.io in the form of .JSON 3d object that contains textures, but also way too many geometries for performance. Here's what the model looks like without any merging:

[image: Original Model]

Here's what the model looks like after merging:
[image: Merged Model]

I understand that the *material* is the same once all meshes are merged into a single meshes, but is there any way to take the textures from the JSON 3d object and merge them as well for the single geometry?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662674/three-js-merging-meshes-but-keeping-seperate-materials